# XML/XSD ISSUE : How do I make two elements with different names always match with each other

Tags: xml, xsd, schema

For example:

```
<Region>
 <RegionID>r1</RegionID>
 <RegionInfor>A</RegionInfor>
 <Subregion>
  <SubregionID>s1</SubregionID>
  <RegionIDAssociation>r1</RegionIDAssociation>
 </Subregion>
</Region>
```

Question:
I want to make RegionIDAssociation always match RegionID, which means if the RegionID is r1, the subregion's RegionIDAssociation has to be filled with r1, how do I achieve it with XML SCHEMA (XSD) ?

Comment: Can someone take a look the question and give some advice ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use key/keyref:

```
 <xs:element name="Region">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="RegionID"/>
        <xs:element ref="RegionInfor"/>
        <xs:element ref="Subregion"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:key name="region-id">
      <xs:selector xpath="."></xs:selector>
      <xs:field xpath="RegionID"></xs:field>
    </xs:key>
    <xs:keyref refer="region-id" name="subregion-constraint">
      <xs:selector xpath="Subregion"></xs:selector>
      <xs:field xpath="RegionIDAssociation"></xs:field>
    </xs:keyref>
  </xs:element>
```

Comment: Yea, it works. I tried this method last night and I found I put it in the wrong scope. Thank you.